# What is RTN short for in RTN_LOCAL?

Tags: kernel, routes, netlink

I am really confused with the name of RTN_LOCAL.

It defined in linux/rtnetlink.h

```
enum {
RTN_UNSPEC,
RTN_UNICAST,        /* Gateway or direct route  */
RTN_LOCAL,      /* Accept locally       */
RTN_BROADCAST,      /* Accept locally as broadcast,
               send as broadcast */
RTN_ANYCAST,        /* Accept locally as broadcast,
               but send as unicast */
RTN_MULTICAST,      /* Multicast route      */
RTN_BLACKHOLE,      /* Drop             */
RTN_UNREACHABLE,    /* Destination is unreachable   */
RTN_PROHIBIT,       /* Administratively prohibited  */
RTN_THROW,      /* Not in this table        */
RTN_NAT,        /* Translate this address   */
RTN_XRESOLVE,       /* Use external resolver    */
__RTN_MAX
```

};

**I found it uesd in many places of Linux kernel.**

1.the return value of inet_addr_type().

2.route type value of fib_alias->fatype.

3.action  value of fib_rule->action.

Comment: @someone_smiley, Do you have any references?

Comment: unfortunately, No. But I and all of my friend always read it as routine. for long time :)

Comment: some one told me long time ago, its old convention